# Module for Integrating jQuery UI Multiselect Widget

Tags: 7, entities, javascript

I am using the [jQuery multiselect widget](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) on another non-Drupal project and I would love to be able to use it with CCK in Drupal 7. I have found [this module for CCK multiselect](http://drupal.org/project/multiselect) but it is not exactly what I want. I realize I could try to write something, but I was curious if anyone has used the above with Drupal before or if there is a module out there I'm missing.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite what you are requesting but thinking that [chosen](http://drupal.org/project/chosen) might be a good alternative to what your searching for.

Comment: I think this is the best solution in most cases

Answer (score 3):

Here you are: [jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_ui_multiselect_widget)

Comment: awesome. this didn't exist when I started this thread

Answer (score 1):

Since this is Drupal 7 isn't it easier just adding the `.js` files to your theme's `js` folder and adding this in your info file?

```
scripts[] = path/to/js/jquery.multiselect.min.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the jquery.multiselect.js and jquery.multiselect.css files to your theme folder, such as /sites/all/themes/your-theme/js/jquery-multiselect/

Then add this to your template.php

```
drupal_add_js(path_to_theme().'/js/jquery-multiselect/jquery.multiselect.min.js');
drupal_add_css(path_to_theme().'/js/jquery-multiselect/jquery.multiselect.css');
drupal_add_js('$(document).ready(function(){$("#example").multiselect();});', array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer', 'weight' => 6));
```

And to make it only show up on certain nodes types, you can use a preprocess node hook in your template.php:

```
function your_theme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($node->type == 'my_content_type') {
    drupal_add_js(path_to_theme().'/js/jquery-multiselect/jquery.multiselect.min.js');
    drupal_add_css(path_to_theme().'/js/jquery-multiselect/jquery.multiselect.css');
    drupal_add_js('$(document).ready(function(){$("#example").multiselect();});', array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer', 'weight' => 6));
  }
}
```